# Insert or update a map

Tags: c++

I have a `std::map`. Given a `<key, value>` pair, I need to:

- Modify the value in the map if the key exists, or
- Insert the  pair into the map if the key does not exist yet.

I'm doing it like this:

```
if (map.find(key) == map.end()){
    map.insert(std::pair<int, char>(key, value));
}
else {
    map[key] = value;
}
```

Is this way of doing it correct? Also, is there a faster or more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: map[key] = value; is sufficient

Comment: `operator[]` will do an insert, if the key doesn't exist

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are various strategies.

The simplest is just to use `operator []`:

```
map[key] = value;
```

however it requires that `value` be default constructible *and* assignable. Furthermore, since those operations take place they might (in some case) lead to performance concerns.

Another solution:

```
auto const result = map.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
if (not result.second) { result.first->second = value; }
```

You of course also incur the assignment cost if you update, but avoid it if the insert works.

For reference, the return value of `insert` is `std::pair<iterator, bool>` which yields an `iterator` to the element inserted or found, and a boolean indicated whether the insert was successful (`true`) or not (`false`).

Comment: How can one avoid assignment cost with given requirements?

Comment: that is actually question to you, "also incur the assignment cost if you update", why to incur what cannot be avoided?

Comment: @Slava: I am sorry, but I don't understand your second comment; English seems not to be your first language, and it is not mine either :/

Answer (score 7):

For C++17 you can use the following code:

```
auto [iterator, inserted] = map.try_emplace(key, value);
if (!inserted) { iterator->second = value; }
```

Or even easier:

```
map.insert_or_assign(key, value);
```

It will work even for key and value types that are not default constructible or not copyable.